# How to find which tweets contain a hashtag by r

Tags: r

i have 5 texts that get from the tweet.
i wonder which one has a hashtag.
[Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlrky.png)
what is the logical vector to find that?

Comment: Please provide sample data so that this problem is reproducible. Right now, it will be difficult for people to help you out. (We don't want to type all the stuff from your image into our R sessions :)

Comment: When you ask a question, you want to provide a reproducible data and a running code. Just throwing your text in a link does not help any SO users. Would you read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? Then, you will understand how you are supposed to ask questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the indices of the tweets that match with `grep`

```
Tweets = c("sefgfg efgwre", "asdwfg #ABC erwthtr", "#wdfv efgv ertbv",
    "wetg rth fgwetgr", "adsfd v verfwf df #ghqwef")
grep("#\\w", Tweets)
[1] 2 3 5
```

If you want to get what the hashtags are, you can do this in two steps with `regexpr` and `regmatches`

```
m = regexpr("#\\S+", Tweets)
regmatches(Tweets, m)
[1] "#ABC"    "#wdfv"   "#ghqwef"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by

```
grepl("#", text)
```

Note, your vector of text data is assumed to be `text`.  This will return a vector of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s.